# camel rest dsl - any way to have GET with json body

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, embedded-jetty

I'm using camel rest java dsl with jetty component.
Camel version is 2.18.0

The route provides a rest service that consumes json formatted request and produces json response. Doing so using POST is no problem.

But since these routes don't change no data, it would be preferrable to use GET as verb.

Is there any way to accept a json body in the upstream together with GET?

Does it depend on the underlying consumer?

Are there any examples to do so or am I fundamentally wrong in trying so?

Thanx in advance
Henning

Answer (score 0):

Jetty component is deprecated as per the docs. You could build your endpoint using [camel-restlet component](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html) , there you can use the *restletMethod* to specify the endpoint method.

Comment: Hi Panayiotis, sorry if my question was missing clarity, I am using jetty as underlying consumer for the camel-rest java dsl. I will edit and make this clearer. Would restlet accept incoming body for GET?

Comment: Well I tried to setup a test for that, but it required match effort to even send a GET with body, (HttpURLConnection automatically converts your req as POST, when you set the outStream), so I cannot certainly tell if camel-rest will accept the body, and then I came across this issue,
 where it says that GET body is not read [CAMEL-9611](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9611)

Comment: Hi Panayiotis, thank you very much for your effort. I will make a short answer that gathers this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I gather, what I came across so far. With the help of Panayiotis answer, [CAMEL-9611](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9611) notes that it seems to be explicitly deactivated, also is swagger missing the possibility to express body in GET requests.

It comes to the point that although the HTTP spec is rather vague about the usage of a body in a GET request, the usage is only seldomly supported by frameworks.

I hoped it would be possible to define complex query input using GET with a json body, since it would be much easier to define more complex queries. But while reading on, I get the impression, that this handling is discouraged because of the lack of support.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1 - "A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request."